# Prevent jquery event running twice

Tags: jquery

I have a click event (see below). The problem I'm having is i'm triggering it but the targ.hide('slow') event is asynchronous and so i'm able to trigger the event again whilst the first targ.hide('slow') is still running. I have managed to solve the problem with a flag but was wondering if there was a better way to go about stopping this? Thanks in advance.

```
var flag = false;
$('div.titlebar div.re.b1 div.r .sides').delegate('.close', 'click', function (e)
{
    if (!flag)
    {
        flag = true;
        var cnt = $('table.sides tbody tr > td').length;
        var targ = $(this).closest('td');
        var side = $(this).parent('div[itemprop]').attr('itemprop');

        if (cnt > 1)
        {
            targ.hide('slow', function () { targ.remove(); LoadSides(dkey); flag = false; });
            updatesidedel(side, true);
        }
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: You should move away from `delegate`, it's all about `on` these days...

Comment: Initially I was using live then was told about delegate but will now look into on. Thanks!

Comment: maby you can rewrite your animation, using `stop( true )`?

Like: `targ.stop( true ).hide( 'slow' );`

Comment: @GomatoX Unfortunately this didn't work as it needs to run an event within the animation to update the cnt variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to check if the `td` is still being animated.

```
if( $('td:animated').length > 0 )
```

Comment: I put an if statement around the code block if ($('table.sides tbody tr > td:animated').length == 0) and it worked great. Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use this : [jquery's :selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to see if your item is currently animated or not.